# Converting String to Double respecting NSLocale in Swift

Tags: swift, localization, number-formatting

I display a Double number as String on the screen in a UITextField. After editing I convert it back to a Double.

This is a unit test method omitting UITextField:

```
func testFoundationDouble() {
    let locales: [NSLocale] = [NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US"), NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "de_DE")]
    let numbers: [Double] = [0.0000001, 0.1, 1, 100000000]

    for locale in locales {
        let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
        nf.locale = locale
        nf.maximumSignificantDigits = 5
        nf.minimumSignificantDigits = 1
        for number in numbers {
            if let str = nf.stringFromNumber(number) {
                if let d = Double(str) {
                    XCTAssertEqual(number, d , "numberst must be equal. original: \(number), String: \(str) converted: \(d), locale: \(locale.localeIdentifier)")
                } else {
                    XCTFail("cant interpret \(str) as Double,  locale: \(locale.localeIdentifier)")
                }
            } else {
                XCTFail("cant format \(number) with locale \(locale.localeIdentifier)")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

test result:

[image: test result]

In essence, NSNumberFormatter works fine converting Double to String for a given locale.

Converting this String back to a Double fails since Double(str) expects the string in an en_US locale.

How can I do conversions from String to Double so that

```
doubleValue == toDouble(nf.stringFromNumber(doubleValue))
```

for any given locale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert the string to a number according to the locale, just
use a number formatter again, i.e. replace

```
if let d = Double(str) {
```

by

```
if let d = nf.numberFromString(str) {
```

Comment: Unforunately this will cut off the decimals

Comment: @user3673952: No, it doesn't. Why do you think it does?